# How to provide a handlebars helper as a block param for another helper

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I am stuck with Handlebars v4.1.2 and trying to employ a pattern I've seen in Ember and other component based frameworks, but I'm having trouble wrapping my mind around the context binding and options passing.

The point is to provide `dropdownMenuItem` for authors to fill out while not actually registering it as a helper that can be used outside of a `dropdownMenu`.

The usage I'd like is this:

```
{{#dropdown-menu label='Menu' as |dropdown-menu-item|}}
  {{#dropdown-menu-item href='https://example.com'}}Example{{/dropdown-menu-item}} 
  <!-- assume that "links" is defined as Array.<{{url: string, text: string}}> -->
  {{#each links as |link|}}
    {{#dropdown-menu-item href=link.url}}{{ link.text }}{{/dropdown-menu-item}} 
  {{/each}}
{{/dropdown-menu}}
```

Here's what I've got so far:

```js
const Handlebars = require("handlebars");

Handlebars.registerHelper('dropdown-menu', function dropdownMenu(options) {
  return new Handlebars.SafeString(`
      <menu class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropdown__trigger">${options.hash.label}</button>
        <div class="dropdown__content">
          ${options.fn(this, {
            blockParams: [dropdownMenuItem]
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    `);
})

function dropdownMenuItem(options) {
  return `
    <a href="${options.hash.url}" class="dropdown__link">
      ${options.fn(this)}
    </a>
  `;
}
```

The error is that the `options` object passed into the `dropdownMenu` function is not defined

Comment: I think you should call the option outside handlebar brackets as it is not a context variable but an internal variable of the helper function:  
`${options.fn(this, {
            blockParams: [dropdownMenuItem]
          })} `  --> `options.fn(this, {
            blockParams: [dropdownMenuItem]
          })`

Comment: Those are not handlebars brackets, that is a javascript template string with a placeholder expression - moving the expression outside of the template string would make no difference.